# Usage of addImageFromBase64

Tags: react-native, image-store

I came across this `addImageFromBase64` function from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagestore#addimagefrombase64

As quoted:

> Note that it is very inefficient to transfer large quantities of binary data between JS and native code, so you should avoid calling this more than necessary. @platform ios

It sounds like a terrible idea to use this function. Wondering if there is any good use case to implement this function?